# Suddenly drop in FPS

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building, nvidia-graphics-card

I built a computer for my cousin some months back. Last week he started getting around 50 fps CS:GO. Given the graphics card is an NVIDIA Geforce GTX 960, it used to run it around 250-300 fps.

I reinstalled Windows on his computer, and the fps was the same. I then moved the graphics card to another PCI slot, and it got the fps back to the initial 250-300 in CS:GO, however. Later that day, my cousin reported that it was back at 50 fps.

I'm thinking the graphics card is defective, but do you have anything in mind that could cause this?

I'm hesitating to send it back; if the graphics card doesn't contain errors, a pretty big fee will be added when they return it.

Edit:
We also tested the FPS on Guild Wars, where the computer was lagging on lowest settings. Where as, it was about 100 fps on the highest settings before.

Edit 2:
I also monitored the heating, and it's not an issue, actually, the graphics card didn't get over 40-50 degrees Celsius whilst running Guild Wars 2. Tried making the fans spin manually, and got them to around 3000 rpm

Comment: Does this only occur when he is playing CS:GO?  If so, (this may seem like a silly question), is there any chance that your cousin has inadvertently edited the `fps_max` setting?

Comment: I should have included that as well :) we tried Guild Wars 2 as well, When it ran okay, he got like 100 fps on the highest settings, and when the card was messing up (like described), it went down to 10-20 fps and lots of lags spikes. Even on lowest settings it would lag, so it's definately not the game, but thanks for you comment! ^^

Comment: At face value, it sounds like an overheating problem.  You may want to monitor temperature, and take a look at his cooling system.

Comment: Sounds like a fault condition where the GPU's clocks are dropping under load, which could be due to a faulty cooler causing overheating. Try using [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) to monitor temperatures—if temperatures are exceeding 90 °C, the card is overheating and you should get it replaced.

Comment: Already did monitor the heating, and it's not an issue, actually, the graphics card didnt get over 40 degrees Celsius whilst gaming. Tried making the fans spin manually, and got them to around 3000 rpm, which sounds ok :), I'm worrying a bit that it's actually "underperforming"

Comment: Is any extra software running which was not running before? E.g. game recording software?

Comment: No, we just formatted it :)

Comment: @DragonLord wouldn't you expect the fps to drop over time, as the card would heat up?

Comment: An overheating GPU would slow down in intermittent bursts as it would throttle in an on-and-off fashion to keep temperatures in check.

Comment: Thank you, I will give GPU-Z a try tomorrow and get back with results :)

Comment: Also clean the CPU's heatsink.